# SQL query show the first if they flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

I have a query for SQL and thats works good. I want the contact information from 2 persons

I use this query:

```
SELECT 
    Contact = STUFF((SELECT ';' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Ad.[Name])) + ', ' + Ba.[IB] + ', ', Ba.[BI] + ', ', Ba.[BN]
                     FROM Ba 
                     JOIN Ad ON Ba.AdID = Ad.AdID
                     WHERE Ad.AdNu = '448412' OR Ad.AdNu = '5444877'
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

They do what I want! But now I want to edit this query, because some persons have 2 adresses and in the table "Ba" is a column thats name is "IsAdress".

These column have 0 for false and 1 for true. Now I want that my list show at the first position the adress with the 1 in the column "IsAdress", but I don't know how change the `WHERE`. How do I get my query !?

Maybe a `WHERE` with other select statement to chek which is the adress is true?

Please help me.

Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Contact = STUFF((
SELECT ';' + LTRIM(RTRIM(Ad.[Name])) + ', ' + Ba.[IB] + ', ', Ba.[BI] + ', ', Ba.[BN]
FROM Ba JOIN Ad 
ON Ba.AdID = Ad.AdID
Where (Ad.AdNu = '448412' OR Ad.AdNu = '5444877')
ORDER BY Ba.IsAdress DESC
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: sorry for the delay, if i use your query. Than i get only the rows if they have the 1 in IsAdress. But i want a list that they first Show the rows with the 1 in IsAdress and than came the rows with the 0 in IsAdress. I want to show al Long list of the data, with 0 and 1 in IsAdress